# How to Update a SQL table using Union

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, union, sql-insert

So I have 2 tables and I want to ***UPDATE*** Table 1 so that it is the Union of Table 1 and Table 2. Any suggestions?

[image: Example Image]

Comment: That's not an UPDATE. An update is where you change the contents of rows that already exist. An INSERT, however, adds new rows to a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks like* you just want to insert rows of `table2` into `table1`. If so:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2)
select col1, col2 from table2
```

You might be looking to a more subtle logic, like,: insert names that do not exist, and update values on name that exist already. If so, I would recommend `on conflict`. For this to work, you need a unique constraint on `table2(col1)`, and then:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2)
select col1, col2 from table2
on conflict (col1) do update set col2 = excluded.col2
```